# Why are brand new out of the box cast iron skillets black?

Tags: equipment, cast-iron, pan, seasoning-pans

Iron is a grey metal. I read that when you cook it turns black from a reaction to the food. But this has never been used.

I tagged utensils but technically this is not a utensil or is it.

Comment: Actually the "equipment" tag might be better (which I added and is awaiting approval). I don't know the answer as to why, but every single one of the cast iron skillets I have seen are indeed black

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unseasoned cast iron is gray, until it rusts. But it’s common for manufacturers to factory-season cast iron, which makes it black. The black color comes from carbonised oil.

Comment: @Sneftel...Well that is very interesting and I never would have guessed. Thank you. I accepted the answer for sure.

Comment: Note that manufacturers specifically season their cast iron black by adding carbon, because that's what people are used to from antique cast iron.